# weird POST request in IIS logs

Tags: iis, logging

I know that stackoverflow is not the correct place to post this question, but i already post this at serverfault and the place seems generally dead.

--

I noticed weird log entries (unless there's something i don't understand) in my IIS (7.5) logs.

it's an online dictionary with requests ( user friendly url rewriting ) and most of them are GET. However I noticed weird POST requests which are taking place by a person who is trying to crawl our content ( tens of thousands of such requests )

```
2013-11-09 20:39:27 GET /dict/mylang/word1 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 200 296
2013-11-09 20:39:29 GET /dict/mylang/word2 - z.z.z.z Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+CPU+iPhone+OS+6_0+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/536.26+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/6.0+Mobile/10A5376e+Safari/8536.25+(compatible;+Googlebot-Mobile/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) - 200 468

2013-11-09 20:39:29 POST /dict/mylang/word3 - x.x.x.x - - 200 2593
```

The two first requests are legal. Now for the third request, I don't think I have allowed cross domain POST. if that what the third log line means.

all those POST requests take that much time for unknown reasons to me. I would like to know how are those POST requests possible and how can I stop them.

p.s. I have masked the IPs on purpose.

any help would be appreciated! thank you in advance.

blocking POST generally is not an option, i extensively use AJAX. i want to know how does he do this kind of POST request and how to stop him. I've got tens of thousands of requests, i constantly ban IP ranges through firewall but he just hops through proxies.

this is how a normal POST request ( through ajax happens ):

```
2013-11-10 10:16:54 POST /dict/mylang/displaySem.php - 85.73.156.122 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:25.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/25.0 http://www.mydomain.com/dict/mylang/randomword 200 171
```

Answer (score 1):

Http allows anyone to POST a request to your site. Your application (not IIS) should check if it is a valid request before starting the long processing algorithm.

Some common validation methods are:

- If you think he is directly POSTing to your site using an automated script, you could use a CAPTCHA to make it hard for him: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA
- If you think he is hijacking the session of other people, you can use a CSRF field in your form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: yes POST-ing is generally allowed since i use AJAX. but that kind of POST (in that specific format url) doesn't seem normal. This is how a normal (AJAX) POST looks like in the logs:

2013-11-10 10:16:54 POST /dict/mylang/displaySem.php - 85.73.156.122 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:25.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/25.0 http://www.mydomain.com/dict/mylang/randomword 200 171

Comment: The 'weird' request is missing the user agent string. Typically an indication that someone is using an automated script. You could also use this in your application to filter the 'weird' requests.

Comment: no it's not just the missing user agent. that POST /dict/mylang/word3 means he is POST-ing to: www.mydomain.com/dict/mylang/word3. Which should be impossible because NONE of my javascript ajax calls points to that form of URL. ALL ajax calls point to specific .php files, such as in the example i provided in the comment above with displaySem.php

Comment: In HTTP a request can be of different types. Eg. GET, POST, DELETE, etc... So your 'attacker' can select whatever type he want's. It seems he selected type 'POST'.

Comment: ah so you mean, he has configured wget or whatever to use POST instead of GET for those urls. i see, well captcha is not possible, i can't have hundreds of visitors use captcha for every word they want to see in the dictionary unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. And protecting agains that is explained in my original answer ;)